# Fetching large data from Elasticsearch in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I am fetching about `60,000` documents from an index `ABC` in Elasticsearch (v7) through their Node.js client. I tried using their recommended Scroll API but it took almost `20s` to do so. Next, I increased the `max_window_size` of the index `ABC` to `100,000` (from the default `10,000`) and the query took `5s`.

I am running Elasticsearch v7 on a 8-core, 32GB-RAM machine. I am not performing any aggregations and my query is just a simple GET request to fetch all documents from the index `ABC`. Is there any way to speed this up to less than one second through their Node.js client?

My code in Express

```js
const { body } = await client.search({
  index: 'ABC',
  size: 60000,
  body: {
     query: {
        match_all: {}
     }
  },
});
res.send(body.hits.hits);
```

If there's no other way to cut the time down, should I cache the entire response in memory and let the UI read from it rather than hitting ES directly (the data only updates once per day, I might not need to perform cache validations). Should I look into Redis for this?

Comment: "_through their Node.js client_" is probably not relevant. https://www.loggly.com/blog/nine-tips-configuring-elasticsearch-for-high-performance/

Comment: I mentioned Node because I can run the Express app on all cores of my machine using Node's Cluster module. Not sure if it can help in parallelizing the requests to ES for a faster fetch.

Comment: Right. My point was I think the optimization is needed in ES. Your approach with node seems solid.

Comment: If NodeJS client supported transport protocol, it would speed up this fetch. Unfortunately, NodeJS client supports just Elasticsearch REST API

Comment: Well if data in your cluster is not being changed during fetching or you don't care about 100% consistency of results I would use *Search After* instead of *Scroll API* it should work much faster.

Comment: @IliaMaskov I updated the question, could you show how to use `search_after` as a parameter in this example?

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm not exactly sure what your use case is, the scroll API is probably not appropriate for a web server servicing a web page. To quote [this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.2/search-request-scroll.html) in the docs:

> Scrolling is not intended for real time user requests, but rather for processing large amounts of data, e.g. in order to reindex the contents of one index into a new index with a different configuration.

Instead, you should **paginate** the results with the [from/size](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-from-size) arguments. When the UI needs to display more items, you should submit another API request to pull another page by increasing the `from` argument appropriately.

Comment: The issue is that I cannot achieve filtering in the datagrid if I paginate. Right now I'm loading all rows and doing pagination on the UI. When I filter for an attribute, the datagrid filters across all the 60k rows. By using `from/size`, I'd lose that feature because the datagrid would not have all the rows to give a complete filter result.

Comment: I see. Could you explain this datagrid a bit more? Would it be possible to just re-submit the API request any time the user changes the filters? Elasticsearch does support filtering, so maybe you could put the filters into the Elasticsearch queries?

Comment: See the "filter context": https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html

Comment: That's what I have been doing, whenever the filter changes, call the API again with needed filters. It loads a subset of those 60k rows but takes time, as in the original case. I think the issue boils down to speeding up the READ operation from Elasticsearch.

Comment: Okay. So, if the filter is being done in the Elasticsearch query, why do you need to load 60k rows? Would you be able to submit the query with a `size` argument, say 25, to load only a single page and send to the client and visualize that in your UI? Then, wait for them to click for the next page OR change a filter, and go through that request-response cycle again? I would think reducing the size of the query result should speed up your READ dramatically.